# Can I redefine the same prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a script that sends more than 10 queries of all CRUD types on 5 tables (some of the `SELECT`s with `JOIN`s). Originally, I used `mysqli_*` functions for all those. Now, to improve security, I am porting the code to use *prepared statements*.

I have no previous experience using *prepared statements* and I have some doubts about what can and cannot be done. For instance lets say I start by a `SELECT` query, then have an `UPDATE` and finally an `INSERT`.

**My question is this:**

Should I repeat the `mysqli_stmt_init` and `mysqli_stmt_close` for each query, or could I initiate once before the first query, `prepare` a statement for each query and use it and finally close it after all queries are done with? In other words, is method 2 OK, or should I stick to method 1?

**Method 1 - No reuse**

```
// SELECT
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT on table 1 and table 2");
...
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// UPDATE
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "UPDATE on table 3");
...
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// INSERT
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "INSERT INTO table 4");
...
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

**Method 2 - Reusing statement**

```
// INIT
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

// SELECT
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "SELECT on table 1 and table 2");
...

// UPDATE
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "UPDATE on table 3");
...

// INSERT
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "INSERT INTO table 4");
...

// CLOSE
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, method 2 is ok.

There is no need to finally close it either, as it will be closed when your script ends.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `stmt_init()` or `stmt_close()`, [mysqli_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns a stmt object and PHP handles the cleaning, the correct order is `mysqli_stmt::prepare` => `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` => `mysqli_stmt::execute`.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli( "host", "user", "pass", "db" );

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?" );
$stmt->bind_param( "i", $id );

$id = 5;

$stmt->execute();
```

You can execute the same statement multiple times with different params, for example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?" );
$stmt->bind_param( "i", $id );

$id = 5;

$stmt->execute();    // executed: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 5

$id = 3;

$stmt->execute();    // executed: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 3
```

But in case of different statements you must prepare each statement separately.

Comment: Thanks. But, I am using the procedural flavor, in which, I am not sure if it is alright to forego the initialization step.